# 2 invalid Column names 'SalesValue' and Ambiguous name 'CostValue' in the Select on SQL

Tags: sql, reporting, sql-server-2014

trying to create a view with the following sql on server 2014

```
SELECT qryReportWSLCurrentQty.Location,
  qryReportWSLCurrentQty.WarehouseName,
  tblStock.SupplierRef,
  qryReportWSLCurrentQty.StockCode,
  SUM(qryReportWSLCurrentQty.SumOfMovementQty)      AS WarehouseQty,
  SUM(qryReportWSLCurrentQty.SumOfMovementQtyBoxes) AS WarehouseBoxes,
  qryDeliveryValue.LastOfMovementDate               AS DelDate,
  [qryCostValueForReports].[CostValue],
  IIf(([qryTotalSalesValue].[NetAmount]IS NULL),0,[qryTotalSalesValue].[NetAmount])   AS [SalesValue],
  IIf([SalesValue]                      =0,-100,(([SalesValue]/[CostValue])*100)-100) AS PerCentUp,
  IIf(([SumOfQty]                      IS NULL),0,[SumOfQty])                         AS ShopStock
FROM ((((qryReportWSLCurrentQty
INNER JOIN tblStock
  ON qryReportWSLCurrentQty.StockCode = tblStock.StockCode)
LEFT JOIN QRYDELIVERYVALUE
  ON QRYREPORTWSLCURRENTQTY.STOCKCODE = QRYDELIVERYVALUE.STOCKCODE)
LEFT JOIN qryTotalStockinShops
  ON qryReportWSLCurrentQty.StockCode = qryTotalStockinShops.StockCode)
LEFT JOIN QRYTOTALSALESVALUE
  ON qryReportWSLCurrentQty.StockCode = qryTotalSalesValue.StockCode)
LEFT JOIN QRYCOSTVALUEFORREPORTS
  ON qryReportWSLCurrentQty.StockCode = qryCostValueForReports.StockCode
WHERE (((tblStock.DeadCode)         =0))
GROUP BY QRYREPORTWSLCURRENTQTY.LOCATION,
  QRYREPORTWSLCURRENTQTY.WAREHOUSENAME,
  TBLSTOCK.SUPPLIERREF,
  QRYREPORTWSLCURRENTQTY.STOCKCODE,
  QRYDELIVERYVALUE.LASTOFMOVEMENTDATE,
  QRYCOSTVALUEFORREPORTS.COSTVALUE,
  IIF(([QRYTOTALSALESVALUE].[NETAMOUNT]    IS NULL ),0,[QRYTOTALSALESVALUE].[NETAMOUNT]),
  IIF(([SUMOFQTY]                          IS NULL),0,[SUMOFQTY])
HAVING (((qryCostValueForReports.CostValue)<>0));
```

when checking the santax before saving it throws 2 invalid column name `'SalesValue'` and Ambiguous column Name `'CostValue'`
this query produces the report headings and value and is what needed as reqested.

Comment: Ambiguous column name means that you have the same column name in both tables when you perform a `JOIN`. You need to specify which column you want to `SELECT`.

Comment: Are you sure you copy/passed the right query?  This doesn't have either of those columns. `(Salesvalue), (CostValue)`

Comment: @Darren Hannay: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Tipp for better reading your question: Use the formatting tools above the question editor. It is painful to separate the SQL from your question. All the best at Stackoverflow

Comment: As xQbert pointed out--that error will only occur if you try to reference either Salesvalue or CostValue without qualifying which table you need to pull these from.  However, the query you posted does not reference either of these, so your error does not match your code.  Please be sure to include the correct code--or all of the code and not just a snippet.

Comment: `SalesValue` is a calculated value within the select, other columns can't reference it by name, unless you use a Common table expression or subquery. So either replace references to it with the formula or build a subquery/cte.  you need to define which table you want costValue from either I would guess QRYCOSTVALUEFORREPORTS based on your group by.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this using simple substitution (formula) for Salesvalue
and thinking you want [qryCostValueForReports].costValue

```
    SELECT qryReportWSLCurrentQty.Location,
      qryReportWSLCurrentQty.WarehouseName,
      tblStock.SupplierRef,
      qryReportWSLCurrentQty.StockCode,
      SUM(qryReportWSLCurrentQty.SumOfMovementQty)      AS WarehouseQty,
      SUM(qryReportWSLCurrentQty.SumOfMovementQtyBoxes) AS WarehouseBoxes,
      qryDeliveryValue.LastOfMovementDate               AS DelDate,
      [qryCostValueForReports].[CostValue],
      IIf(([qryTotalSalesValue].[NetAmount]IS NULL),0,[qryTotalSalesValue].[NetAmount])   AS [SalesValue],
   IIf(IIf(([qryTotalSalesValue].[NetAmount]IS NULL),0,[qryTotalSalesValue].[NetAmount])                      =0,-100,((IIf(([qryTotalSalesValue].[NetAmount]IS NULL),0,[qryTotalSalesValue].[NetAmount]) /[qryCostValueForReports].[CostValue])*100)-100) AS PerCentUp,
   IIf(([SumOfQty]                      IS NULL),0,[SumOfQty])                         AS ShopStock
    FROM ((((qryReportWSLCurrentQty
    INNER JOIN tblStock
      ON qryReportWSLCurrentQty.StockCode = tblStock.StockCode)
    LEFT JOIN QRYDELIVERYVALUE
      ON QRYREPORTWSLCURRENTQTY.STOCKCODE = QRYDELIVERYVALUE.STOCKCODE)
    LEFT JOIN qryTotalStockinShops
      ON qryReportWSLCurrentQty.StockCode = qryTotalStockinShops.StockCode)
    LEFT JOIN QRYTOTALSALESVALUE
      ON qryReportWSLCurrentQty.StockCode = qryTotalSalesValue.StockCode)
    LEFT JOIN QRYCOSTVALUEFORREPORTS
      ON qryReportWSLCurrentQty.StockCode = qryCostValueForReports.StockCode
    WHERE (((tblStock.DeadCode)         =0))
    GROUP BY QRYREPORTWSLCURRENTQTY.LOCATION,
      QRYREPORTWSLCURRENTQTY.WAREHOUSENAME,
      TBLSTOCK.SUPPLIERREF,
      QRYREPORTWSLCURRENTQTY.STOCKCODE,
      QRYDELIVERYVALUE.LASTOFMOVEMENTDATE,
      QRYCOSTVALUEFORREPORTS.COSTVALUE,
      IIF(([QRYTOTALSALESVALUE].[NETAMOUNT]    IS NULL ),0,[QRYTOTALSALESVALUE].[NETAMOUNT]),
      IIF(([SUMOFQTY]                          IS NULL),0,[SUMOFQTY])
    HAVING (((qryCostValueForReports.CostValue)<>0));
```